# Adding an NSLayoutConstraint prgrammatically, crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I have an app in which I'm trying to apply `NSLayoutConstraint` to an item that is inside a view. Here is my code:

```
[customCell.infoView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[customCell.infoLabel]-0-|" 
         options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customCell.infoView)]];
```

I don't know what this means, but it crashed with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
customCell is not a key in the views dictionary. 
H:|-0-[customCell.infoLabel]-0-|
```

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Notice the caret symbol at the end of infoLabel.

And yes, I do have a `customCell.m`. (I used other objects in it from this .m file).

**Update**

Here is the current code that I inserted in `customCell.m` at `awakeFromNib`

```
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_infoLabel]|"
                                      options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_infoLabel)]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_infoLabel]|"
                                      options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_infoLabel)]];
```

Which crashes with the same error in the above screenshot.

**Update 2**

It now crashes with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings failed because either one of the values is nil, or there's something wrong with the way the macro is being invoked.  Cannot assign value nil for key "_infoLabel". Keys:(

    "_infoLabel"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be in the custom cell's .m file, and then you can refer to the view as _infoView (you're also using infoLabel in one place and infoView in another). Also your constraint is wrong. The constraints should be added to infoView's superview, not to infoView. You also need some vertical constraint as well.

```
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_infoLabel]|" 
         options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_infoLabel)]];
```

Comment: the last word in your code says '_infoLabel` It crashes by mine when I do that, so I just put in self. I did everything you said (besides for the `_infoLabel`, and it still crashes with the same error above

Comment: @MikeRally  Edit your question to show the code you're using now. Does your cell have a property called infoLabel?

Comment: @MikeRally, self is just wrong. Try _infoLabel again. It works when I try it. Is infoLabel the name of a property in your cell?

Comment: Updated my code. InfoLabel is defined in customCell.h and is added in mainVC.m

Comment: @MikeRally, I've never seen that error before. Show how you are declaring infoLabel.

Comment: I declare it in mainVC.m at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The label only gets added on selection of the cell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70542/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-mike-rally).

Answer (score 0):

It's not your mistake.

The way the views dictionary works is kinda weird; it will recognize "." as a keyPath.

The (ugly) solution:

assign customCell.infoView to another view object and use that in the views dictionary,

i.e. `UIView newInfoView = customCell.infoView;`

Comment: I did what you told me to do, and it's crashing with the same error. Updated question with a screeshot